# Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных

Tags: wordpress, база-данных, openserver

Являюсь абсолютным новичком в этом деле. Была установлена старая версия Open Server.  Установил новую версию Open Server. В папке domains создал новую папку. Зашёл в PHPMyAdmin, создал базу данных с именем папки. Короче, всё сделал по учебнику. Когда в Моих проектах открываю проект с именем созданной папки выдаётся "Ошибка установки соединения с базой данных". Можете максимально доступно сказать, как это исправить. Ещё раз повторю, что являюсь абсолютным новичком.

Comment: Скорее всего в конфиге указаны неверные доступы к БД. Найдите в корне папки где лежит WordPress файл wp-config.php и внесите верные доступы к БД.

Answer (score 0):

Раньше по дефолту там был пустой пароль, сейчас пароль по умолчанию root. 100% причина в этом.

Answer (score 0):

У меня причиной была недостаточность GRANT'ов для усера на созданную для WP базу. Нужно было в MySQL для него дать "всё" (примерно так: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON aca.* To 'romleon'@'localhost';`).